# AngularJs styling a single clicked element within an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I have a collapsible accordion using ng-repeat to render its options. On the right there is a downward facing glyphicon. This glyphicon should become upward facing once the job is clicked and expanded.

**Update**: Using Amine's response, the clicked header gets a glyphicon-down as it should be. But when collapsed and clicked outside, the glyphicon stays downward as the index is set and actually needs to become upward facing again when collapsed. How can I set $index to undefined again when the item is clicked again?

[image: glyphicon bug]

My code:

```
<div class="col span_2_of_3">
        <div ng-repeat="item in jobs">
            <accordion>
                <accordion-group ng-click="state.selected = $index">
                    <accordion-heading>
                        <h2>
                            "{{item.title}}"
                            <i class="pull-right glyphicon "
    ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': $index == state.selected,
          'glyphicon-chevron-down': $index != state.selected }"
                            ng-click="state.selected = $index"
                            ></i>
                        </h2>
                    </accordion-heading>
                    {{item.description}}
                </accordion-group>
            </accordion>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my controller I have:

```
$scope.state = { selected: undefined };
```

Comment: please give a jsfiddle demo link. the glyphicon-chervon-down always added to DOM elements. you must only added it to DOM if $index ! = state.selected

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not really possible for me to setup the routing, controllers and data coming from an internal data source to a public jsfiddle. The code I provided should be sufficient to point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The glyphicon-chevron-down should always be visible, only on a clicked expanded job it should become glyphicon-chevron-up

Comment: ok first time you load page the  the following condition is true for all items ($index != state.selected).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not removing the `glyphicon-chevron-down` class when you click on the element. You end up with an element that has both classes ; whatever CSS rule comes last will be applied.

Try this :

```
<i class="pull-right glyphicon " 
   ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': $index == state.selected,
              'glyphicon-chevron-down': $index != state.selected }"></i>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/a256z7ja/1/) is a fiddle showing a solution (note that I have removed the `ng-click` binding on the icon as that's already handled by the `accordion-group`).

Comment: Great! That makes sense, thank you for explanation and working code. Although the chevron-down only becomes a chevron-up again once another job is clicked. I will adjust my code and img as it's hard to explain.

Comment: Then you need to change your `ng-click` directive to something like `state.selected = (state.selected != $index ? $index : undefined)`, so that when you click on the selected element, it goes back to the initial state.

Comment: I've got it like that but it's not working yet, I'll try to get it fixed. Thank you again @Amine.

Comment: You're welcome, @Harbinger. I just realized you had 2 ng-click that do the same thing, one in the `accordion-group` and the other on the icon. You should remove the inner one (I'm gonna update my answer with a jsFiddle).